# Second print statement is not running in the given code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

###### I am running the following code in google colab notebook

```py
from itertools import permutations

p = permutations([1, 2, 3])
print(list(p))

for i in list(p):
  print(i)
```

In the above code first, `print(list(p))` statement prints but second `print(i)` does not show any result.

Can anyone know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: interesting, I believe it's because you already consume the iterator `p` the first time you call `list(p)`

Comment: try assigning the value to a variable like `L = list(p)` and then iterating over `L` - that should work in this case

Answer (score 3):

`p` is an iterator. It can only be consumed once. Since the 1st `list(p)` already consumes it, the 2nd `list(p)` will give an empty list. If you need to consume it multiple times, you need to materialize it as a list:

```
p = list(permutations([1, 2, 3]))
print(p)

for i in p:
  print(i)

[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```